# Using ssh to connect to a windows machine, I can create a folder or delete a file, but can't create a file

Tags: windows, ssh

I am using ssh.exe of cgywin to connect from one windows machine to another.

I can run command such as these:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' testcomputer -1 username 'cmd /c del C:\text.txt'
```

or

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' testcomputer -1 username 'cmd /c mkdir C:\test'
```

However, if I try to create a file using something like

```
echo text > C:\text.txt
```

then I get "The system cannot find the path specified". Why is this happening? If I don't have the proper permission, then how is that I can delete file?

(If I create a file in C:\users\username, then it would work)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that windows will not let any user other then an administrator write directly to the root of this filesystem, hence it will not let you create a file via ssh.

its more to do with file system permissions on why it wont let you create but will let you delete.

Windows 7 this command will let you inherit permissions to do it as a normal user

`icacls C:\ /grant:r "USERNAME":(OI)(CI)M /T /C`

Comment: But it is perhaps a good policy not to let anyone write to the root directory by default.